# Screen flickering

Tags: display

Got a BenQ computer screen, since a while back it's been flickering alot, mostly in games like Leauge of Legends and World of Warcraft. 
My question is why, and could it depend on my graphic card, I've updated it to the latest, and not so long ago I formated my comp. 
thanks ahead.

Comment: By latest, you mean latest drivers I presume? Could have to do with the refresh rate.

Comment: yah, latest drivers. The refresh rate should be fine

Comment: What are the details of your setup? Is this an external monitor plugged into a laptop? What type of video connection are you using (VGA, DVI, HDMI, DisplayPort)?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that happen quite a lot of times. This is what worked for me:

1. turn on/off vsync and test the changes
2. turn off antialising/ansitropic and once more test the changes
3. experiment with a lower refresh rate
4. turn off ATI A.I. (if you have an ATI card)

if none of this work, try one of these drivers:
[Omega Drivers](http://www.omegadrivers.net/")